# Structured Data Testing Tool breadcrumb error

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, structured-data

I am using schema.org (Breadcrumb) and the open graph protocol on my website. Googles Structured Data Tesing Tool mixes them both and throws out an error.

You can copy and paste the code to the tool to see the error messages.

What did I misunderstood or did wrong? Thanks for any help.

Here is the code:

```
<html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
  <head>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/examples/example" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Examples and so on" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="A lot of examples here" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/example.jpg" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol class='breadcrumb' vocab='http://schema.org/' typeof='BreadcrumbList'>
      <li property='itemListElement' typeof='ListItem'><a property='item' typeof='WebPage' href='/'><span property='name'>Home</span></a><meta property='position' content='1'></li>
      <li property='itemListElement' typeof='ListItem'><a property='item' typeof='WebPage' href='/examples'><span property='name'>Examples</span></a><meta property='position' content='2'></li>
      <li property='itemListElement' typeof='ListItem'><a property='item' typeof='WebPage' href='/examples/example'><span property='name'>Examples and so on</span></a><meta property='position' content='3'></li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rdfa(opengraph) and microdata(schema) cannot be used on same html page

"3) We’ll continue to support our existing rich snippets markup formats. If you’ve already done markup on your pages using microformats or RDFa, we’ll continue to support it. One caveat to watch out for: while it’s OK to use the new schema.org markup or continue to use existing microformats or RDFa markup, you should avoid mixing the formats together on the same web page, as this can confuse our parsers."

Source: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2011/06/introducing-schemaorg-search-engines.html

Comment: I should note, the BreadcrumbList implementation in this example is in RDFa, not Mircrodata. There is not Microdata in the above example.

there is a bug with the BreadcrumbList in the Microdata Format, so RDFa or JSON-LD are the preferred formats for BreadcrumbList.

OP didn't do anything wrong from a Schema standpoint, this is a Google issue with parsing.